# How to avoid 'No space left' on Bazel build?

Tags: caching, build, out-of-memory, bazel

Running a lengthy Bazel build on a near-full device, I encounter this error:

> **ERROR:** I/O error while writing action log: No space left on device

However, I can't quite free up some space on the device, so I must manipulate the cache and/or the temporary storage somehow. I've noticed that Bazel's cache at `~/.cache/bazel/myproject/` can get pretty big, so I was wondering, can I:

- delete some files in there after I get the error ?
- move that cache somewhere else ?
- disable the cache altogether ?

[Bazel's User Manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html) seems to indicate that the `--[no]use_action_cache` would kind of do that third option (though I don't know how efficient that would be), but it would slow things down.

As for the temporary storage, I do have a location with enough space, so I simply called `export TMPDIR=/path/to/morespace/`. So if I could move the cache, that would be where it's going.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1035

Comment: Oh thanks @Jin, I'll make sure to follow that issue. Any temporary fix (i.e. not a full cache managing system) like the 2 first options I asked about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the startup option [`--output_base`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--output_base) to point to a location where there's more available storage. This will tell Bazel where to write all its outputs.

```
$ bazel --output_base=/path/to/more/space build ...
```

To avoid specifying this for every command, add it to your project `<project>/.bazelrc` or user `~/.bazelrc`:

```
startup --output_base=/path/to/more/space
```

Comment: Just making sure here: this will delete the progress of a failed build, right ?

Comment: I don't think it will delete the current artifacts in ~/.cache, but it will start fresh in the new location. A hack is to copy the project's `$(bazel info output_base)` to the new location.. but that may not work as expected.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I assume if the error didn't break anything, that should work too.